# Amazon S3 validating access token , secret , region and bucket

Tags: python, validation, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using amazon s3-boto3 with python to put some files at amazon s3 bucket

before running the code i want to make a validation for the 
access token , secret , region and bucket
to ensure all the data are correct without waiting for the exception when executing my code.

i checked the documentation and make a search at google with no luck

any help ?

Comment: There is no `DryRun` for `put_object`. What exactly do you want to validate?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the token credential become show stopper before a massive batch processing, you can try execute a small put_object() to test whether the access is denied.

Because many different roles can be specify inside IAM policies and ACL, this is the only feasible ways to validate the access.